# TapRecognizer in View and Scrollview (to drag and drop images in a view)

Tags: iphone

Iphone-I created a view and a scrollview. The scrollbiew have images inside their view. I'd like to implement a method which makes it possible for the user to drag images on a view from scrollview list?
plz help me!

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good example how to do it:
[ScrollViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html)